# Oracle regexp_like square brackets inside character set

Tags: oracle, plsql, regular-expression, regex

This questions is in regards to Oracle, pl/sql, and the regexp_like function.

I am trying to build a character set that will match on all typical special characters. My character set currently looks like:

```
pattern := '[-~`!@#$%^&*\(\)\\{}_+=|''";:,./?]+';
```

I would like to add the square brackets to this character set, however, whatever I try to add ']' is not working. Here is a simple example that illustrates the problem:

```
select
  case when regexp_like('w]ord', '[\]]+') then 'true'
  else 'false' end
from dual;
```

This returns false, meaning it did not match the ']' character. Curiously, I can get the '[' character to match because this returns true:

```
select
  case when regexp_like('w[ord', '[\[]+') then 'true'
  else 'false' end
from dual;
```

Comment: I don't think backslash is needed for escaping "]".     `select
  case when regexp_like('w[ord', '[]]+') then 'true'
  else 'false' end
from dual;` works just fine

Comment: @a1ex07 I could be wrong, but I think []]+ is getting matched because [] is an empty character set, and then ]+ is a closing square bracket. So it's correct that it matches, but the closing square bracket is not in the character set. I need it in the character set.

Comment: More testing show that I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the backslash has a special meaning within the brackets. You can either use it as it is: `regexp_like('a]b','[]]')` or use an `or`: `regexp_like('a]b','([whatever]|\])')`.

Any reason you can't use `regexp_like('a]b','[^[:alnum:]]')`?

Comment: Yep, I see that now [^[:alnum:]] seems like a good option, but it may match more than I'm willing to accept. Using the pattern: [][~`!@#$%^&*()\{}_+=|''";:,./?-]+, seem to do exactly what I want, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Why don`t  you dip into the manual  [SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm#i690819), Appendix D, Oracle Regular Expression Support:

> []
>
> Bracket expression for specifying a matching list that should match any one of the expressions represented in the list. A non-matching list expression begins with a circumflex (^) and specifies a list that matches any character except for the expressions represented in the list.
>
> To specify a right bracket (]) in the bracket expression, place it first in the list (after the initial circumflex (^), if any).
>
> To specify a hyphen in the bracket expression, place it first in the list (after the initial circumflex (^), if any), last in the list, or as an ending range point in a range expression.