# Oracle: REGEXP_LIKE: Strings with angle brackets aren't found (whether they are escaped or not)

Tags: oracle, java, regex

The following question will answer my original question, plus many others. What would the correct syntax be to do a REGEXP_LIKE search (in Oracle Database 12c) for this string (which exists somewhere in a CLOB)? In other words, pretend like you want to find this exact string:

```
%.,"'?!:#$&)(*;+-/<>=@[]\^_{}|~
```

using:

```
"select * from my_table where regexp_like (some_column, '" + regexSearchString + "')"
```

Now, from everything I've read, you would need to transform the string by escaping the necessary characters  (`\  ^  .  $  |  (  )  [  ] *  +  ?  {  }  ,`) to get it to work, like this:

```
%\.\,"'\?!:#\$&\)\(\*;\+-/<>=@\[\]\\\^_\{\}\|~
```

Now I haven't tested every non-escaped character like &, _, or %, but I have found that searches with < or > are not found. Even though REGEXP_LIKE is not needed in the following example, say I wanted to find all occurrences of `><div class=`, for whatever reason. Is there an additional thing that needs to be done to get it to correctly treat angle brackets just like any other letter?

Comment: You can check the manual as proposed here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/109294/2047

Comment: there is nothing special with angle brackets. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/6074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 1 from dual where
regexp_like('%.,"''?!:#$&)(*;+-/<>=@[]\^_{}|~', 
            '%\.,"''\?!:#\$&\)\(\*;\+-/<>=@\[\]\\\^_\{\}\|~');
```

This gives, as expeced, 1.

You must escape `.?$)(*+[]\^{}` and `|`

You do not need to escape `,` (but it works nonetheless):

```
select 1 from dual where
regexp_like('%.,"''?!:#$&)(*;+-/<>=@[]\^_{}|~', 
            '%\.\,"''\?!:#\$&\)\(\*;\+-/<>=@\[\]\\\^_\{\}\|~');
```

This works:

```
select 1 from dual where
regexp_like('<div>Lets check for an <strong>inner</strong> tag :)</div>', 
            '<(\w+)>[^<]*</\1>');
```

Gives 1. So does what you ask for:

```
select 1 from dual where
regexp_like('<p>Lets get <i>this</i><div class="example">example going :)</div></p>', 
            '><div class=');
```

For which you don't even need regex, by the way.

EDIT:
By guess is, that you are using a programming language to build your SQL. In that case, it is highly likely that you are not properly escaping your . If you want the SQL to include `'\.'` (an escaped .), you need to escape it for your lanuage too: `'\\.'`
Likewise, if you want `'\\\^'` you'd need to write `'\\\\\\^'`